# Oracle Database, extract string beeing between two other strings

Tags: regex, oracle, regexp-substr

I need a regexp that's combined with regexp_substr() would give me the word being between two other specified words.

**Example**:

source_string => `'First Middle Last'`

```
    substring varchar2(100);
    substring := regexp_substr(source_string, 'First (.*) Last'); <===
```

this doesn't work :(.

`dbms_output.put_line(substring)` ===> output should be: `'Middle'`

I know it looks simple and to be honest, at the beginning I thought the same.
But now after spending about 3h for searching for a solution I give up...

Comment: So, in your example, you are looking for a "word" (however defined) between the very specific words 'First' and 'Last'? What if there are two or three words between 'First' and 'Last'? And can either 'First' or 'Last' appear **more than once** in the input string? (And if so, what is the desired result from that?) Also: Why is `regexp_replace()` part of the problem statement, and not part of one possible solution? Do you **have** to use regular expressions and ignore all solutions that do not use regular expressions?

Comment: I'm sure that these three words will appear only once. Omg I just noticed that I wrote regexp_replace when I mentioned regexp_substr... . Im sorry. I don't have to use regular expressions. If you have some better idea how to do it will be more than welcomed :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because the literal strings `'First'` and `'Last'` are being looked for. Assuming that the strings don't all literally begin `'First'` you need to find another way to represent them. You've already done this by representing `'Middle'` as `(.*)`

The next point is that you need to extract a sub-expression (the part in parenthesis), this is the 6th parameter of [`REGEXP_SUBSTR()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions164.htm#SQLRF06303).

If you put these together then the following gives you what you want:

```
regexp_substr(source_string, '.*\s(.*)\s.*', 1, 1, 'i', 1)
```

An example of it working:

```
SQL> select regexp_substr('first middle last', '.*\s(.*)\s.*', 1, 1, 'i', 1)
  2    from dual;

REGEXP
------
middle
```

You can also use an online regex tester to validate that [`'middle'` is the only captured group](https://regex101.com/r/vkdpEH/1).

Depending on what your actual source strings look like you may not want to search for exactly spaces, but use `\W` ([a non-word character](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_posix003.htm#SQLRF55544)) instead.

If you're expecting exactly three words I'd also anchor your expression to the start and end of the string: `^.*\s(.*)\s.*$`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! You saved me so much time, thank you! Oh and actually I will have a long text and I will be looking for these exact three words and I will not know only the middle one. My goal is to find out what it is and your example does that! Thank you once again!

Answer (score 1):

If source string always looks the same, i.e. consists of 3 elements (words), then such a simple regular expression does the job:

```
SQL> with t (str) as
  2    (select 'First Middle Last' from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(str, '\w+', 1, 2) result from t;

RESULT
------
Middle

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

`(\S*)` pattern might be used with `regexp_replace` and `regexp_substr` as in the following way to get the middle word :

```
with t(str) as
(
 select 'First Middle Last' from dual
)
select regexp_substr(trim(regexp_replace(str, '^(\S*)', '')),'(\S*)') 
    as "Result String"
  from t;

Result String
-------------
Middle
```

in the first step `First`, and in the second one `Last` words are trimmed.

Or, More directly you can figure out by using `regexp_replace` as

```
with t(str) as
(
 select 'First Middle Last' from dual
)
select regexp_replace(str,'(.*) (.*) (.*)','\2') 
    as "Result String"
  from t;

Result String
-------------
Middle
```

Comment: Thank you! Your regexp works well for three words but because I was not specific enough I forgot to mention that the actual text will be much longer and that these three words will be just a part of that. But anyway, great regexp, thank you!